# Remove Legal Notice IN Registry

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I have a very slow laptop that I need to reboot 3 times a day.  It is connected to a Windows domain.  I have managed to get it to auto-logon, but I still get prompted to hit ok after reading a legal notice.

I have cleaned out `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]` and exported it.  I import it every 10 minutes via a script.

How can I permanently remove the legal notice.  A new laptop is not an option right now.

Answer (score 5):

Two options for a permanent fix:

1. Have the group that manages your domain's group policies put you into an exception OU that doesn't enforce the legal notice.
2. Remove the laptop from the domain.

Answer (score 4):

You need to talk to whoever is in charge of the Active Directory domain.  They have the legal notice set via Group Policy; it will always come back.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the Legal Notice thing will not make your computer faster to boot (not by any appreciable amount, anyway).  Most likely, you should consider using the following tools:

```
Start -> Programs -> Accessories -> System Tools -> Disk Cleanup
Start -> Control Panel -> Add / Remove Programs
Start -> Programs -> Accessories -> System Tools -> Disk Defragmenter
```

`Add / Remove Programs` will allow you to remove old software you no longer need (be careful to not remove something you actually do need).  Disk Cleanup will allow you to automatically remove temp files, etc, that are taking up unnecessary space.  Finally Disk Defragmenter will automatically rearrange files on your laptop's hard drive for optimal efficiency.